# Axiom and Flask POST and GET requests, passing arguments

Tags: python, flask, vue.js, axios

I am learning how web apps work and after successfully creating connection between front and back end I managed to perform get request with axiom:

**Route in my Flask**

```
@app.route('/api/random')

def random_number():
    k = kokos()
    print(k)

    response = {'randomNumber': k}
    return jsonify(response)
```

**my kokos() function**

```
def kokos():
    return (890)
```

**Function that I call to get data from backend:**

```
getRandomFromBackend () {
        const path = `http://localhost:5000/api/random`
        axios.get(path)
        .then(response => {this.randomNumber = response.data.randomNumber})
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

Now suppose I have an input field in my App with value that I want to use in the function kokos() to affect the result and what is going to be displayed in my app.. Can someone explain me how to do that?
 Is this what POST requests are for and I have to post first and then get?  Or can I use still GET and somehow pass "arguments"? Is this even GET and POST are for or am I making it too complicated for myself?

Is this the proper way to do these kind of thing? I just have a lot of code in python already written and want to simply exchange data between server and client.

Thank you, Jakub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add second argument

```
axios.get(path, {
    params: {
      id: 122
    }
  })
  .then ...
```

You can pass `id` like this or anything it will be available in `get params` at `python side` like `we pass in URL`.

> python side [Flask] (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#accessing-request-data)

**To access parameters submitted in the URL (?key=value) you can use the args attribute:**

```
def random_number():
  id = request.args.get('id', '')
  k = kokos(id)
```

id will be passed kokos function if no id is provided it will be blank ''

you can read `axios` docu to make complex requests.

> https://github.com/axios/axios

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank you, By get params do you have sys.argvs from https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html in mind?

Comment: Hi, I managed to buil my simple app and everything works fine...I moved my app to pythonanywhere.com and cal run it. Problem however is that my function makes the get requets to http://localhost:5000/api/random. Funny enough - i get the proper result if I also run my flask app on my local machine but no if I turn it off. How can I make the request to API that is running on pyhonanywhere server?

Comment: you need to change this path const path = `http://localhost:5000/api/random` in live => to const path = `http://pythonanywhere.com/api/random`